# SVN - how to take a file off the version control

Tags: svn

I am working on a SVN controlled project that I had checkout from server at the beginning.

In one of the SVN controlled directory, there is a configuration file (settings.py) which I had to edit to suit my local setup.

I have created a local backup of my own configuration file. In order not to update this file to server, I always revert "settings.py" before committing to the server. After committing, I move my own "settings.py" from my local backup.

I will appreciate if somebody can guide me how to exclude this file from SVN without any side effects; so that I don't have to revert and recopy by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common way to do this is to store an example file such as `settings.py.template` in source control, but *not* `settings.py`. That way, you can change `settings.py` as needed locally, without Subversion prompting you to commit it.

When you make a new checkout, you would copy `settings.py.template` to `settings.py` to get things started. If you make any changes that affect the default configuration file, change `settings.py.template` and commit the change.

Comment: this is what I typically do too, plus I will set svn to ignore settings.py

Comment: This is a good partion solution...I think you could combine it with svn:ignore to make the perfect solution.

Comment: Actually, we use a similar approach. We have a dir etc/ for config files, and etc.deploy for the *real* config files that go into deployments for RTM. Works well; only caveat is to keep the files in sync (new settings etc.).

Comment: can somebody show an example of how to issue svn:ignore command to the already included file?

Comment: @Tolga: Subversion will not ignore a file that is already in the repository. To use this method, you would *delete* the `settings.py` file from the repository (or use `svn mv` to rename it to `settings.py.template`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply not commit the file.

When committing, you can select what to commit; just omit the file.

Comment: Yeah, simply uncheck the file, if using tortoise.

Comment: assuming the OP is using tortoise.

Comment: I think using svn:ignore makes more sense here...so you don't have to uncheck the file every single time you make a commit.